# ECHOing paths in batch

Tags: batch-file

So, I'm having problems ECHOing one of the lines to a file.
The code is as follows:

```
IF NOT EXIST "%rutaSteamIdle%\tf2idle.ini" (
(
ECHO [Settings]
ECHO steam_location = C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam
ECHO secondary_steamapps_location = 
ECHO sandboxie_location = C:\Program Files\Sandboxie
ECHO api_key = 02FE9AB5998EA5F8A3E0DA7C4C47F3C7
ECHO backpack_viewer = Backpack.tf
ECHO launch_options = +exec idle.cfg -textmode -nosound -low -novid -nopreload -nojoy -sw +sv_lan 1 -width 640 -height 480 +map itemtest
ECHO launch_delay_time = 120
ECHO log_file_formatting = {date}, {time}, {itemtype}, {item}, {id}, {account}{nline}
ECHO easy_sandbox_mode = no
ECHO sys_tray_notifications = hats,tools
ECHO close_to_tray = False
ECHO log_web_view = On
ECHO log_web_view_port = 5000
ECHO ui_no_of_columns = 2
ECHO ui_window_size = (1024, 768)
ECHO ui_account_box_font_size = 12
ECHO ui_account_box_icon_size = 40
ECHO ui_account_box_icon = 
ECHO ui_log_entry_toggles = system,hats,weapons,tools,crates
ECHO log_poll_time = 1
ECHO ui_log_background_colour = 000000
ECHO ui_log_font_colour = FFFFFF
ECHO ui_log_font_size = 12
ECHO ui_log_font_family = TF2 Build
ECHO ui_log_font_style = 0
ECHO ui_log_font_weight = 50
ECHO ui_log_font_strikeout = False
ECHO ui_log_font_underline = False
)>>"%rutaSteamIdle%\tf2idle.ini"
)
```

When running this, I get 'flashed' (the cmd window stays open for a second before closing itself) the following error:

```
\Steam was unexpected at this time.
```

Am I missing something here?
If I make the line like this:

```
ECHO steam_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"
```

It ECHOes correctly, but sadly that's something I can't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Path to Steam contains a closing parenthesis. You need to escape it like this:

```
ECHO steam_location = C:\Program Files (x86^)\Steam
```

`cmd`'s parser isn't very nice with those things. This is inside a parenthesised block and thus the first unescaped (or unquoted, but quoting doesn't work here since `echo` will output the quotes as well) closing parenthesis will end the block. And the part after that in the same line will be interpreted as the next command, in this case `\Steam` which leads to the error message you got.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this...

```
SET "steam_location=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"
ECHO %steam_location%
```

it will give you output as

> C:>ECHO C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam

I hope this works :)

Comment: That will not help in the context of the parenthesized IF statement. It would work if delayed expansion `!steam_location!` is used instead.